# Calling public methods in module pattern dynamically

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid in my web page with module pattern as follows:

```
var foo = (function(){
 function f1(){
  //do something
 }

 function buildTemplate(sourcecolumn){
    if(sourcecolumn) { //..return a span with formatting }
    else //..return a span with source column as inner text
 }

 function buildGrid(){
  //1. setup for grid 
  //.. add datasource to fetch records from db
  //2. build columns
  //..foreach over columns and send the template function
  var columns = [];
  for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
    columns.push({
       template: '#= buildTemplate(colname) #',
       width: 50
    });
  }

 }
 return {
   init: function(){
     //..bind click events
   }
 }
})();

$(document).ready(foo.init);
```

When I ran the page which will trigger the `buildGrid()` method, browser console shows `buildTemplate()` is not defined. Because the `buildGrid` is execute later when a button is clicked and the `buildTemplate()` is not a public function to execute.

Currently I've moved buildTemplate() outside of [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) scope so that the function is already executed and the grid is able to display values. But, I don't want to expose the buildTemplate function to be public.

Is there a way I can still encapsulate the `buildTemplate()` method inside IIFE scope with prior execution ?

**EDIT**

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVPa5/230/), which actually has kendo grid binding with module pattern. The grid won't show any data as the `Simple` function is inside of foo scope. If you move the Simple function outside of the scope the the [data is shown](http://jsfiddle.net/JVPa5/229/) in the kendo grid.

Is it possible to wrap up the template function inside of `foo` scope ?

Comment: What horrible template system are you using that requires global functions? Are you sure you cannot pass a closure instead?

Comment: There is no template system. just a plain html, which will have this js file in it

Comment: Then what is `template: '#buildTemplate(colname)#',`? Where does it get processed?

Comment: oh. typo error. It is `template: '#= buildTemplate(colname)#'`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the question remains: What system processes this property in which a string refers to a function?

Comment: Its how the [kendo template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) system works. If you want to display a value based on some logic, then we can supply a function like a string, which kendo will process and display the value returned from that function

Comment: Can you show us the location where `template` is called on `columns`? That's probably where you should fix this.

Comment: Hey @Bergi. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVPa5/228/), that actually created with module pattern and kendo grid. If you actually move the `simple` function out of dom ready the data will be binded.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JVPa5/230/

Comment: Passing the functions as a part of the data source seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/JVPa5/231/ - that way they are in scope together with the variables they operate on.

Comment: @Bergi Any other alternatives other than this approach.

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: @Bergi Any alternative approaches to module pattern ? Can any other pattern fix this problem ?

Comment: No, you would have to make the function global, and you really don't want that.

Comment: Appreciate your help @Bergi. I'm thinking to raise a bounty after couple of days